# c++ libCurl : how to accept expired certificate using libCurl

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

I am working on Linux embedded application which acts as client and receives data from https server using libCurl. My application's requirement is to accept expired certificate and continue to connection establishment.

I could not find any such option that can be set using curl_easy_setopt as we can ignore -
 - verification of the certificate's name against host => setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 0
 - verification of the authenticity of the peer's certificate => setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE

Any there any other way out I can try to make it work.

Comment: Have you tired the suggestions? Please update!

Answer (score 3):

You can set a callback using CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION (see example at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html) where you can manipulate the SSL context, clear errors, etc.

This will probably not be enough, you can experiment with setting some options of openssl itself, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html.

I'm not sure if it is enough to set SSL_VERIFY_NONE or if you actually have to supply a validation callback function that says yes to everything.

I haven't tested this and I'm not sure it will actually work, but you can certainly try.